# How to get String value of an object instead of object values?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I want to populate `spinner` from `sqlite` database. After I am retrieving the relevant data it **showed junk values**. Could you please help me to fix this. I will attach my codes here.

**--java File--**

```
public class AddNewMovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner movieTypes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_new_movie);
        movieTypes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinMovieType);

        loadSpinnerData();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_new_movie, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void loadSpinnerData() {
        // database handler
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements


        List<MovieType> lables = db.getAllMovieTypes();


        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<MovieType> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MovieType>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        movieTypes.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

**-- DBHelper--**

```
 public List<MovieType> getAllMovieTypes() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        List<MovieType> lst = new ArrayList<MovieType>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, null, COLUMN_STATUS + "=?", new String[]{"A"}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                String type = cursor.getString(1).toString();
                MovieType movieType = new MovieType(type);
                movieType.setTypeId(cursor.getInt(0));
                lst.add(movieType);
            cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return lst;

    }
```

I just want to show the **movie types** from the database. Please help me. this code returns the object values. but I need the string value of it. I have tried to convert my object to string. but I couldn't find a proper way to fix it. Actually I am very new to Android. so please help me.

Comment: @saku..welcome to SO..please add relevant code that specifies your exact problem instead of the full java code.

Comment: create custom Adapter by extending `ArrayAdapter` class

Comment: Now you would I have upvoted your question also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to **Override** `toString()` method in your **MovieType** class

```
    public class MovieType{

    //Whatever fields you have here

     //Override toString()
     @Override
        public String toString() {
            return your_field_name;  

            /***put the field name which you want to show in spinner
                            Or 
                You can append multiple fileds
                return field1 + field2+......;
           ***/
        }
    }
```

And your all set, you would then see the value of the field in your `spinner`, what you have set in `toString()` method.

Comment: Please accept and upvote if it helps you which helps me also.

Comment: i can't upvote since i dont have 15 reputation. i accepted it as an answer. Thnks

Comment: Thanks a lot Clairvoyant.

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom adapter or you can make your list of String type.
As you have mentioned that you just want to show movies type. You can do this in your getAllMovieTypes() function.

```
public List<String> getAllMovieTypes() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, null, COLUMN_STATUS + "=?", new String[]{"A"}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            String type = cursor.getString(1).toString();
            lst.add(type);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return lst;

}
```

Now, you can display only type.

Comment: Nice idea but we can do that in `MovieType` class without changing the code.

Comment: hhmm I am from Udaipur saw your profile your from Delhi. Are you new to Android?